# get local machine timestamp using google script

Tags: forms

I am working on a google form. The requirement is to close accepting responses to a google form at a certain time interval (for example, May 03, 2017 local time).

So, what we intend to do is write a script that closes responses to the form as soon as the local machine timestamp (here local machine timestamp is the user machine timestamp) changes to May 04, 2017.

However, all attempts are resulting datetime in timezone set up File/Project Properties/Timezone instead of user's local timezone.

How can we get user's machine date/time so as to compare it with the set time for rejecting responses and apparently close the form.

Comment: Show us your code. Are you sure this design cannot be bypassed?

Comment: @Jeroen: Thank you... Here's the code:

function myFunction() {
  var CloseDate = new Date('May 01, 2017 18:00:00');
  var CurrentDate = new Date();
  if (CurrentDate > CloseDate)
  {
  function stopAcceptingResponses() 
    {
      FormApp.getActiveForm().setAcceptingResponses(false);
      informUser_("Your Google Form is no longer accepting responses"+" "+CurrentDate);
    }
     informUser_("Your Google Form is now accepting responses"+" "+CurrentDate);
  }
  }

Comment: Our requirement is to get the local time of the user and compare it to a standard time, if the standard time is of past for the local user, stop accepting responses.

Hope this helps...